# Как изменить регистр буквы, используя replace и регулярное выражение?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив строк (поля в бд, они с нижним_подчёркиванием).
Есть точно такой же набор полей у объекта, но с одним маленьким нюансом - вместо православного_нижнего_подчеркивания тамКашеобразныйCamelCase.
Задача - пройтись по массиву, и собрать из него массив соответствующих значений из объекта.

Хотел сделать так:

```
const params = [
    'field_one',
    'field_two',
    'justfield',
    'field_three',
    'longer_than_one_field'
];
const data = {
    fieldOne:1,
    fieldTwo:2,
    justfield:'d',
    fieldThree:3,
    longer_than_one_field:'____'
}
params.map(key => data[key.replace(/_(.)/g, '$1')]);
```

Но не знаю как изменить регистр $1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В совпадении первый символ - нижнее подчёркивание, а второй - любой символ, который *захватывается в группу №1*.

В [`RegExp#replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) можно передать метод обратного вызова в качестве аргумента замены. См. *Передача функции в качестве второго параметра*:

> В качестве второго параметра вы можете передать функцию. В этом случае функция будет выполнена после произошедшего сопоставления. Результат вызова функции (её возвращаемое значение) будет использоваться в качестве строки замены (обратите внимание: описанные выше специальные шаблоны замены в этом случае не применяются). Обратите внимание, что функция будет вызвана несколько раз для каждого полного сопоставления, если регулярное выражение в первом параметре является глобальным.
>
> Функция принимает следующие аргументы:
>
> `match`    Сопоставившаяся подстрока (cоответствует шаблону замены $&, описанному выше).
> `p1, p2, ...`    n-ная сопоставившаяся подгруппа из объекта `RegExp` в первом параметре метода `replace()` (cоответствует шаблонам замены `$1`, `$2` и так далее, описанным выше). Например, если в качестве шаблона передано регулярное выражение `/(\a+)(\b+)/`, параметр `p1` будет значение сопоставления с подгруппой `\a+`, а параметр `p2` — с подгруппой `\b+`.
> `offset`    Смещение сопоставившейся подстроки внутри всей рассматриваемой строки (например, если вся строка равна `'abcd'`, а сопоставившаяся подстрока равна `'bc'`, то этот аргумент будет равен `1`).
> `string`    Вся рассматриваемая строка.

Таким образом, можно передать первые 2 аргумета: полный текст совпадения и значение первой группы, а вывести только изменное значение первой группы.

```js
const params = [
    'field_one',
    'field_two',
    'justfield',
    'field_three',
    'longer_than_one_field'
];
const data = {
    fieldOne:1,
    fieldTwo:2,
    justfield:'d',
    fieldThree:3,
    longerThanOneField:'____'
}
console.log(params.map(key => 
    data[key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, ($0,$1) => $1.toUpperCase()) ]
));
```

Тут `$0` — полный текст совпадения, а `$1` — значение первой группы.

Выражение `/_([a-z])/` найдёт только те `_`, после которых находится ASCII-буква в нижнем регистре.

Answer (score 0):

Гугл показал, что оказывается replace может принимать callback в качестве второго аргумента:

```js
const params = [
    'field_one',
    'field_two',
    'justfield',
    'field_three',
    'longer_than_one_field'
];
const data = {
    fieldOne:1,
    fieldTwo:2,
    justfield:'d',
    fieldThree:3,
    longerThanOneField:'____'
}
console.log(params.map(key => data[key.replace(/_(.)/g, match => match[1].toUpperCase())]));
```